# Writing Rendered HTML To A File

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a web app that displays a table the user can edit.  In the process of editing, various inner HTML of the original table gets replaced with edits made by the user.  Once the user is finished I would like to save the resulting table in a .html file so that I can include it in a PowerPoint slide without having to recreate it.  Basically I want to capture the .aspx file as is after editing and write this to a file.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Are you looking to save the file on the client or the server?

Comment: Also are you doing the editing client side via javascript, or through postbacks to the server?

Comment: Way too vague... I have no idea how you're implementing your solution, and that's a huge part of any answer.  On top of all that, you didn't actually ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically I want to capture the .aspx file as is

Because you state "capture the ASPX", I'm assuming the data edits are persisted somewhere (memory/database). This means it is straightforward to override the `Render()` method of the control/page and redirect (or copy) the output stream to a file.

### Example

```
protected override void Render( HtmlTextWriter writer ) {
    using( HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter( new StringWriter() ) ) {

        base.Render( htmlwriter );
        string renderedContent = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();

        // do something here with the string, like save to disk
        File.WriteAllText( @"c:\temp\foo.html", renderedContent );

        // you could also Response.BinaryWrite() the data to the client 
        // so that it could be saved on the user's machine.

        // and/or write it out to the output stream as well
        writer.Write( renderedContent );
    }
}
```

### Sequence

- User enters data
- You store the results somewhere
- You re-render the control with the most recent content
- Capture the output of the control and write it out to a file

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it client side you can do something like this using jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/BAVzC/3/

You can then copy paste to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few pointers.

You can get the whole inner html of a section of your page using jquery functions like [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

You can use ajax to send this to your server.

You could write an http handler to receive this at the server. Since you only plan to save this to a fixed format html file, nothing else is required. I would not use a page to so as to avoid the extra overhead of creating all the controls, and a page will not receive html input unless you set `ValidateRequest` to "false".